# Simply XOR encrypt in Javascript and Decrypt in Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, xor

The purpose for this is not highly security-relevant and the key will be long, so I'm just wanting to use simple XOR encryption to the strings.

Well, the Javascript on the client is as follows:

```
function dc_encrypt(str, key)
{
   var ord = []; var res = "";

   var i;
   for (i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {ord[String.fromCharCode(i)] = i}

   for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
       res += String.fromCharCode(ord[str.substr(i, 1)] ^ ord[key.substr(i %    key.length, 1)]);

   return(res);
}
```

And the Java is is:

```
public String dc_decrypt(String str, String key)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   sb.append((char)(str.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(i % (key.length()))));
   return(sb.toString());
}
```

Unfortunately this produces some very weird results. Some letters differ after encrypting in JS, sending the result through a POST and decrypt in Java.
In every case it doesn't seem to be reliable.

I assume the issue must have something to do with encoding... does someone know a more reliable solution for this?

Huge thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you provide sample input, and the differing outputs in the two implementations?

Comment: Try to encode your encrypted output using Base64 and then decode it in Java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When XOR-encoding two strings, the resulting XOR-values of the individual characters sometimes do not result in characters that can be displayed.
Therefore one solution is to encode the result as a sequence of hex-values and then to decode these hex-values on the server side.

**Javascript:**

```
function encryptStringWithXORtoHex(input,key) {
    var c = '';
    while (key.length < input.length) {
         key += key;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        var value1 = input[i].charCodeAt(0);
        var value2 = key[i].charCodeAt(0);

        var xorValue = value1 ^ value2;

        var xorValueAsHexString = xorValue.toString("16");

        if (xorValueAsHexString.length < 2) {
            xorValueAsHexString = "0" + xorValueAsHexString;
        }

        c += xorValueAsHexString;
    }
    return c;
}
```

**Java-Code:**

```
private static String decryptStringWithXORFromHex(String input,String key) {
    StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
    while (key.length() < input.length()/2) {
        key += key;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<input.length();i+=2) {
        String hexValueString = input.substring(i, i+2);
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(hexValueString, 16);
        int value2 = key.charAt(i/2);

        int xorValue = value1 ^ value2;

        c.append(Character.toString((char) xorValue));

    }
    return c.toString();
};
```

Example:
Encode in Javascript:

`encryptStringWithXORtoHex('Encrypt This','SecretKey');`

returns the string `160b00001c043f452d3b0c10`

Decrypting in Java:

`decryptStringWithXORFromHex("160b00001c043f452d3b0c10","SecretKey")`

returns `Encrypt This`

**Please note: the shown solution only works for characters that have a charChode value of less or equal than 255. If you want to use the solution for unicode characters (e.g. €) you will have to change the code to take care of this.**